# Change a build-in dataframe in R by mistake, how to change back

Tags: r, dataframe

I changed one column of the build-in data frame Marriage by mistake in R. How can I change back? I closed the R-studio and re-open, but, the data frame remained the changed one I made.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to reload it? (`data(Marriage)` ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data remains the same because in your options, you have set to save your global environment. Rstudio reloads it when you start a new R session. I have been lamenting that restoring environments is a very bad practice, but nobody listens to the mad person on the soap box.

What to do? Well, easy. You think you modified the built-in data.frame, but... you didn't. You just touched on the copy. Feel free to remove it and whenever you refer to it again, it will find the original copy. Here's an example on a built-in dataset `ToothGrowth`.

```
> ToothGrowth$len <- NA
> head(ToothGrowth)
  len supp dose
1  NA   VC  0.5
2  NA   VC  0.5
3  NA   VC  0.5
4  NA   VC  0.5
5  NA   VC  0.5
6  NA   VC  0.5
> rm(ToothGrowth)
> head(ToothGrowth)
   len supp dose
1  4.2   VC  0.5
2 11.5   VC  0.5
3  7.3   VC  0.5
4  5.8   VC  0.5
5  6.4   VC  0.5
6 10.0   VC  0.5
```

or you can reload it (as @Cath suggested)

```
> ToothGrowth$len <- NA
> data("ToothGrowth")
> head(ToothGrowth)
   len supp dose
1  4.2   VC  0.5
2 11.5   VC  0.5
3  7.3   VC  0.5
4  5.8   VC  0.5
5  6.4   VC  0.5
6 10.0   VC  0.5
```